CSS mix blend mode black and white
I'm having a bit of trouble with how mix-blend-mode works. I want the text color to be black when it is on a white background, and when it is on all other colors (because it is on an image) the text color should be white. How can I make it so?
In this case I have the following code:
.header-title {

padding: 20px;
font-size: 85px;
font-weight: 900;
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
color: white;
margin-right: -202%;
font-family: 'Bahnschrift Condensed', sans-serif;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);}



Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

Thats not how mix blend modes work - they mix the background, so they obviously don't just default to a full fill color in some cases and not others.

Does this answer help?
